# Access class member function from catch clause?

Tags: javascript, class, angular, this

I've a service, which returns an `Observable`, on which I map to parse the response and a catch clause to catch errors if any. The problem however is that I need to update a data member in the handler method and it's shared to other components for use.

```
import { stuff } from 'stuffs';

class AppService() {
    private errorMsg = new Subject<string>();

    // ... More methods here

    private handleError(error) {
        // Problem - `this` here doesn't point to AppService
        this.errorMsg.next('Sharable error message to component!');

        return Observable.throw(error.message);
    }

    callLoginApi(userDetails: {email: string, password: string}):        
         Observable<any> {
             return this.http.post(this.postURI, userDetails)
                         .map(this.extractData)
                         .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
```

or

```
.catch(err => this.handleError(err));
```

Comment: Oh, I'm such a fool! Thank you @Günter